Unresolved reference: LocalContext in Composable function
I have converted a java class to kotlin class. I want to get context in Composable function. However, I get error which is unresolved reference for LocalContext.
@Composable
fun test(){
    val context = LocalContext.current // LocalContext unresolved reference.

}


I figure out this issue. When i add "implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")", the problem is gone.

You need to import it before you can use it:
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext

Your IDE should even be able to do this (semi-)automatically. In Android Studio, for example, you can press Alt+Enter while the text cursor is placed somewhere on LocalContext.

I figure out this issue. When i add "implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")", the problem is gone.
